# .htaccess adding new file

Tags: .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /homepage/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /homepage/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

That is my .htaccess code. I have created new file in homepage/test.php and when i visit it from browser it give error of access,
 `i have tried by replacing index.php with test.php but it still not working`.
Can some one explain me how this code work and why not my code is working.

```
i have deleted .htaccess but its still not working. What else file it can be.
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate clearly what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
RewriteRule . /homepage/index.php [L]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule (.+) /homepage/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

P.S. For this to work, your index.php needs to listen for $_GET['page'] and load the appropriate resource.

EDIT: without using the "?page=$1" your code will just display the index page for all requests that are not files or directories. I am not sure if that is what your were going for.

Comment: @Wasim Okay, my apologies. What you want to do (assuming /homepage/ is a physical directory) is remove `RewriteBase /homepage/` from the file, create an new .htaccess in the /homepage dir, then cut and copy the remaining directives to it. Also, do this: `RewriteRule ^.+$ index.php [L]`

Comment: its still not working. what i did is, copy,paste above code and remove line RewriteBase /homepage/ ..... and replace last code line with RewriteRule ^.+$ index.php [L] and this .htaccess file is in homepage director. i think i did as you guide but still now working.

Comment: This may seen like a silly question but, is mod_rewrite enabled in your Apache config? You are using the IF statement so if it wasn't enabled, Apache would simply skip over your rewrite directives.

Comment: it is live in server and its obviously set mod_rewrite